# GUI For Writing Questions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, editor

I find it a little complicated to use a code-like editor for entering in questions. Why do I have to learn another flavour of a text based editing language.

A simple GUI would be awesome. This means you can hide the preview and "how to format" boxes making the whole page much cleaner.

Comment: Because Markdown > BBcode

Comment: I Want Graphical User Interface(GUI) Program For Insertion Sort In C Programming Language

Answer (score 6):

After learning Markdown, it takes much less time to format text. For example, if I wanted to bold text with a GUI, I would have to take my hands off the keyboard and click on the `B` button. However, with Markdown, I can simply type two asterisks, the text I want bolded, and then two more asterisks. While this may seem more complicated, it's actually much faster once you get the hang of it.

That said, if I understand you correctly, there are icons that you can click if you don't want to learn Markdown. They should be appearing above the textbox. If you don't see them, please do tell.

Comment: I agree it's faster once you know it.

But for new people surely a GUI is going to be a shorter learning curve.

I wonder what the ratio is between first time posters and repeat posters.

That would ultimately determine which option would be more useful.

Comment: @resolve what do you mean by a "GUI"?

Comment: @notPekka A rich text editor, similar to CKEditor etc. [Example](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just click on the buttons above the text field, if you don't want to learn the formatting characters/keyboard shortcuts? You can format using these buttons and what you see in the preview window is what you get.

Isn't that GUI enough?

Comment: I agree. I'm a bit lost on what the OP means by "A simple GUI"; the toolbars seem like exactly that

Comment: @MichaelMrozek The OP doesn't want separate markup (/down) and output displays, and is instead looking for a rich text editor.